# Suppressing attributes from aggregations

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, python-3.6, repr

`BigTuple` inherits tuple and aggregates list. The `__repr__` does not work as expected. That is should produce `BigTuple(*(1,2,3))`, but instead uses the `repr` function of the list it aggregates. How can I suppress this behavior and use the `__repr__` defined in the class `BigTuple`. I aggregate the list because I want to sort the items provided at initialization

I have tried not aggregating list. Example:

```
self.__values = values
```

instead of the aggregation:

```
self.__values = sorted(values)
```

See main code below

```
class BigTuple(tuple):

    def __init__(self, *values):

        self.__values = sorted(values)

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        assert hasattr(other, "__iter__")," Not an iterable"

        self.__values.extend(other)
        return self.__values

    def __repr__(self):  
        return 'BigTuple(*{!r})'.format(self.__values)



 cd = BigTuple((1,2,4,[5]))

 repr(cd)  # [1,2,4,[5]] instead of BigTuple(*(1,2,4,[5]))
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Your example gives `BigTuple(*((1, 2, 4, [5]),))` for me.

Comment: @Georgy I have replaced the third line in the class body. Can you check to see if it still works for you?

Comment: Still can't reproduce it. Now it gives `BigTuple(*[(1, 2, 4, [5])])`